# How do I check if a twitter users likes has been updated without exceeding twitters rate limit? (Tweepy)

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, bots, tweepy

I need to check if a user has liked a new post without exceeding twitters rate limit.

Basically, I'm just making a fun code to prank my friend. It will detect when he likes a new post and send that post to him with some snarky comment. All love between me and him, and I've made it obvious who made the bot.

I understand what the rate limit is and why its there, and I have wait_on_rate_limit = True, but that stops the code from working.

Here's what I currently have.

```
import tweepy, random

comments = open('dumbcomments.txt', 'r')

# Authenticate to Twitter
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("authkey", "securityauthkey")
auth.set_access_token("accesstoken", "securityaccesstoken")

# Create API object
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit = True)

lines = comments.readlines()  

friend = api.get_user(friendUser)

likes = api.favorites(friendUser, count = 1)
lastlike = likes


while True:

    likes = api.favorites(friendUser, count = 1)

    if likes != lastlike:
        comment = random.randint(0, 23) 

        api.send_direct_message(friend.id, lines[comment] + '\n' + str(likes[0].text))

        lastlike = likes

comments.close()
```

The code works, so long as I haven't exceeded the rate, which happens quickly.

Comment: At the moment, your code is basically constantly looping. There's a rate limit of 75 calls in 15 minutes for the favorites/list endpoint, so you should space out your calls to check every 15-20 seconds to avoid hitting the limit.

Even then, I would recommend checking the Twitter Developer Policy and particularly the Automation Rules as this could get reported pretty quickly.

Comment: I understand that idea, so I suppose that my main question is if there is a way to check for updates without having a constant loop running?

Comment: The only other option would be to use the Account Activity API, but in order to do that, you'd need the user you are interested in to authenticate into your app, which would be taking "pranking" to a different level.